# Como hacer que en la consulta me muestre los datos solo con 1 decimal en Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

quisiera que el promedio de los sueldos base aparecieran con un solo decimal

```
SELECT A.NOMBRE_ALUMNO, A.RUT_ALUMNO, A.SUELDO_BASE, (AVG(B.NOTA_FINAL)) AS 
NOTA_PROMEDIO_CURSOS, A.SUELDO_BASE * AVG(B.NOTA_FINAL)/100 AS MONTO_BECA
FROM ALUMNO A JOIN REGISTRO B
ON B.RUT_ALUMNO=A.RUT_ALUMNO 
GROUP BY A.NOMBRE_ALUMNO, A.RUT_ALUMNO, A.SUELDO_BASE
HAVING AVG (B.NOTA_FINAL) > 5.5
ORDER BY NOTA_PROMEDIO_CURSOS ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cualquiera que sea tu campo numerico que quieras formatear a dos decimales, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
Suponiendo una tabla t y un campo float n, para formatearlo a dos decimales sería asi:

```
select to_char(n,'FM9999999.90') from t;
```

Espero te sirva.